# Windows 7 image in VMware will allow network connection out but not HTTP

Tags: windows-7, networking, vmware, virtualization

I am currently trying to create a set of images to deploy on my network, but I've run in to a snag. When I create my own Windows 7 image I can successfully use NAT for connecting to the network but whenever I try to access a webpage I get nothing.

To be more specific, all firewalls/iptables are disabled on my host machine, my virtual machine, and my network. I can do lookups and all addresses respond correctly (I'm even using Google's DNS). On the host OS I have full connectivity. On the virtual machine I can ping any device I want and all addresses resolve correctly. Within a browser I cannot reach any page via hostname or IP. I feel almost like port 80 is being blocked but I can't find any reason this would be the case.

If anyone has had this occur before, I would love some insight to the problem.

Comment: Does it not work in other browsers as well?

Comment: the problem isn't browser specific, it's this way with any http gets.  This issue is not only blocking web browsing, but also windows updates and a bunch of installation downloads.

Comment: You have disabled the windows firewall right?  No antivirus on the guest?

Comment: All hardware and software firewalls are disabled and no antivirus is running.

Comment: Truthfully, I'd like to figure out what the issue is here, but I've gone ahead and thrown another image up on my home ESXi box and I'll just work off of that.  In other words; I've given up.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Window 7 image in vmware will allow network connection out but not http](http://superuser.com/questions/151229/window-7-image-in-vmware-will-allow-network-connection-out-but-not-http)